# Creating a new Min() and Max() column based another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create two columns in a new dataframe base on the Min and the Min from an existing dataframe. When groupby is used, it is giving min and max NAN values

```
df.groupby('street').min()['sold_price']
df.groupby('street').max()['sold_price']
```

sample from existing dataframe.

```
street_name sold_price
A            100,000
A            200,100
B            50,000
B            100,000
```

new dataframe should be

```
street_name   min        max
A             100,000    200,000
B             50,000     100,000
```

Comment: Please, review the documentation about using .groupby() and .agg()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
(df.groupby("street_name", as_index=False)
    ["sold_price"].agg(["min","max"])
)
```

---

**Update**: for rename:

```
(df.groupby("street_name", as_index=False)
    ["sold_price"].agg({'low':'min', 'high':'max'})
)
```

Comment: Can I rename the aggregated columns from "min" and "max" to "low" and "high"